# C++ Test - Does sign bit 1 always mean negative?

Tags: c++, number-formatting

I was just taking a C++ test and I got the following question wrong:

**Q: What is the output of the following program?**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    for (int8_t i = 1; i > 0; i <<= 1)
        a++;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

There were the following answers to choose from

- 8
- 7
- Undefined Behavior
- Compile Error

The "*correct*" answer was 7. If there was "Implementation-Defined Behavior" in the answers, I would choose that, so I chose Undefined Behavior which was sort of the closest. I understand that in sign-and-magnitute, 1's complement, and 2's complement the answer will be 7. But doesn't the C++ standard theoretically allow any other number representations? For example, sign and magnitude, but 0 means negative?

Am I correct in that the real correct answer to this question should be Implementation-Defined Behavior, and if not, could you please explain why the answer is 7 regardless of the implementation?

I read the comments to the question and it appears that initially the type of `a` was char, which apparently had raised a lot of complaints about whether `char` is signed or not, so the testsetter changed it to int8_t. As a bonus question, is `<stdint.h>` part of C++? O_O

Comment: `<stdint.h>` is part of C++ (included for compatibility with C). There's a C++ version of it, `<cstdint>`.

Comment: Any sane C++ implementation should provide `stdint.h`, but in C++11 there is officially `cstdint`.  (@AlexeyFrunze: C++11 only!)

Comment: [Implementations don't even have to provide `int8_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5254321/168175)

Comment: @Flexo: yeah, it seemed odd to me that `int8_t` was used to clarify that a `char` was signed - they could have just used `signed char`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: The problem with signed char is that it doesn't have to have 8 bits :)

Comment: Unsigned values represented in a signed integer type are required to have the same *value representation* as the same value in the corresponding unsigned integer type. So I don't think sign and magnitude where a `0` sign means negative would be allowed. (On the other hand, I'm pretty sure the `<<=` is evil when applied to signed datatypes)

Comment: The test is wrong. The correct answer is UB.

Comment: What a strange "test". What knowledge, exactly, is this testing? If you have to *wonder* whether the code is UB or not, no sane programmer would ever write it.

Comment: Another possibility is that it won't compile, because `int8_t` is not defined. That would be unusual, but on a system that doesn't have an 8-bit integral type, `int8_t` won't exist.

Comment: Related: [Why does left shift operation invoke Undefined Behaviour when the left side operand has negative value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-oper)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would say it is undefined (and not implementation-defined) for a different reason.

From 5.8:3

> The value of `E1 << E2` is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>
>   , reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: I reckon that makes both UB and compiler error correct then since they don't specify which compiler it's using.

Comment: No, it is undefined behavior and nothing else. Of course, the compiler is free to deal with UB in any way it likes (including producing a nice, simple compile error), but if the question is what ISO C++ says the result of that program should be, then the only correct answer is UB. :)

Comment: I think you're missing a `^` character in the first `E1 x 2 E2`.

Comment: So his program has undefined behavior because he has signed overflow (because the 1 rolls off the bit pattern when shifting left)?

Answer (score 7):

If the implementation provides the optional `int8_t`, the answer should be correct, from the [C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) which C++11 references regarding stdint;

> 7.18.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>
> The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding
> bits, and a **two’s complement representation**. Thus, int8_t denotes a signed integer
> type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

Comment: Well, this doesn't address the other important fact, what happens when you shift 1 into the sign bit. And that is UB, actually.

Comment: This is interesting though. Does this only apply to the `intN_t` types? Or does C11 also require "normal" integer types to be two's complement?

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure C++11 doesn't reference C11. Wouldn't it reference C99 rather?

Comment: @jalf Yep, it says so (mentions C99) explicitly at the very beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Since the immediate question was answered, I'll answer the bonus question: `<stdint.h>` is a C header which is available in C++. However, use the modern C++ header [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) instead.