# Advantages and disadvantages between int vs int_fast8_t

Tags: c

While I was learning datatypes in c. I came across `int_fast8_t` and `int_least8_t` data types. I did not know these, So I have googled it. I have found some answers here:

[The difference of int8_t, int_least8_t and int_fast8_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254051/the-difference-of-int8-t-int-least8-t-and-int-fast8-t)

The answers are `int_fast8_t` is fastest but Iam surprised what things makes it fast. What techniques does compiler use to make it fast ? and also, When there exists `int` datatype and `short`,`long` modifiers to modify int size. What is the need of this (`int_fast8_t`) datatypes ?

If `int_fast8_t` is faster then we can simply ignore `int` and go for `int_fast8_t` always, since everyone needs speed.

Is there any limitations for `int_fast8_t`?  What are the advantages or disadvantages between `int_fast8_t and int`.

Comment: Well, to start with the bit-widths of `int` versus `int_fast8_t` might be different, meaning you can't really use `int_fast8_t` safely except as an 8-bit integer.

Comment: Ultimately, use it as if you were limited to that exact number of bits. The only problem to cope with is overflow/underflow, in which case you should be using a least-width type. If you know what you're doing or know something won't overflow, then a fast type may be beneficial. Safety first. :-)

Comment: Even a least width type won't make overflow/underflow defined. There is no guarantee there will be a type of the exact size requested on a given architecture, like, there are architectures where int_least32_t might be 36 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int_fast8_t` is the fastest integer type that's at least 8 bits wide. There is no reason to think that it'll be faster than `int` (which is typically the fastest integer type there is.)

Besides, the two types could have different width, meaning they often can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: so kindly let me know which is better to use int_fast8_t or int ? if iam aware my machine is specific of 8 bit size . should i go for int_fast8_t ?

Comment: @niko: In a nutshell: use `int` until there is a clear, specific and measurable need to use something else.

Comment: Iam done with your answer and kindly one last thing what is the need of int_least8_t?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is compatibility if you ever move your code from one architecture to another.

`int_fast8_t` will probably be the same as `int` since in most (many? some?) architectures the `int` type is defined to be the size of the native word (32 bits for a 32 bit architecture, 64 bits in 64 bit architecture). Basically, `int_fast8_t` is saying that, if I'm interpreting correctly, that the underlying type will be the fastest that can hold at least 8 bits of information.

If you move your code to different architecture you can be sure you'll still have at least 8 bits to work with if you use `int_fast8_t`. You can not be sure of that if you simply use `int`.

Comment: @Leushenko  Agree about minimum size of `int`.  Thus, in conforming C, `int` on an 8-bit architecture is _not_ the "size of the native word" as @GSP suggest.  (embedded processor are still often 8-bit.)

Answer (score 3):

For example, on a 32-bit platform, `int` is 32-bit, The CPU might have instructions to operate on 32-bit chunks of data. It might not have such instructions for 8-bit data. In this case, the CPU probably has to use some bitwise operations to process 8-bit types data.

On such platform, `int_fast8_t` may be implemented as 32-bit `int`. But you can't use it as a 32-bit `int`, you can only use it like a 8-bit type without undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually, only the `intptr_t` and `intNN_t` exact width types (and their corresponding unsigned types prefixed with 'u') are not required. `int_leastNN_t`, `int_fastNN_t` and `intmax_t` are all required. This is true for the values of NN where NN = 8, 16, 32, and 64. However, the fast types are not guaranteed to be the fastest on that platform. All that is guaranteed is the signedness and width requirements being satisfied.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune You are right, it's in C11 7.20.1.3, fixed my answer.