# type unsigned long long int is it enough for 1 - 10^9 range?

Tags: c, types

**Consigne**: each integer is in the inclusive range 1 - 10<sup>9</sup>.

I use variable with the type `unsigned long long int`

Is it enough for the stated range?

Comment: it's platform dependent. Use `stdint.h` and `uint64_t` (note that `uint32_t` is enough for such ranges)

Comment: 1e10 is outside 32 bit range, yes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: But you're correct here of course. I'll stop trolling your comments ;-)

Comment: No, don't use `uint64_t` unless you need a type with 64 bits *and no more*.  `uint_least64_t` is more portable (at least theoretically).

Comment: What does “each integer” mean? Each integer your program will read and store in an object? Or will your program do various arithmetic on the values, so that, although the input values are limited to 10^9, more bits are needed to accommodate the arithmetic that will be performed on them?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It's not platform-dependent. The C language defines minimum acceptable ranges for each type, and even plain `long` is sufficient for OP's needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10^9 is way smaller than 2^32

So in your case, no need to use `unsigned long long` (it fits, yes), which is overkill and can lead to slower operation.

Use the proper type, normalized in `stdint.h` include: `uint32_t` or `uint_least32_t` ([uint32_t vs uint_fast32_t vs uint_least32_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779537/uint32-t-vs-uint-fast32-t-vs-uint-least32-t))

`long` is also guaranteed to be [at least 32 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), so it's a good & simple choice as well.

Comment: Prefer `uint_least32_t` (or `uint_fast32_t`) for portable code.

Comment: `uint_fast32_t` is a bad idea. It's misdefined on many real implementations including glibc/x86_64 in ways that both waste memory and hurt performance. Use `uint_least32_t` or just `unsigned long` or even `long`.

Comment: you're right, `long` is simple and 32 bit at least. Why bother with normalized types?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is (assuming that you are adopting the notation `10^9` to mean `1e9` - `^` is the XOR operator in C, and `10^9` is `3`).

An `unsigned long long` has to be capable of storing a number between 0 and 2<sup>64</sup> - 1. Your maximum is much smaller than this.

Note also that an `unsigned long` has to be capable of storing a number between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup> - 1. Your maximum is also smaller than this.

Comment: and even `signed long` is capable of storing a number over `1e9`.

Answer (score 1):

Long long unsigned integer type. Contains at least the [0, +18,446,744,073,709,551,615] range;
Specified since the C99 version of the standard.

source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: As the page says: That applies to C99. Before that the rules were something something like 16 bit <= int <= long <= long long But it's always best to use the uintXX_t types from stdint.h

Comment: I'm not sure, but correct me if I'm wrong.  In pre C99, the type `long long` did actually exist? or was it only a `gcc` extension?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but you don't need `unsigned long long`, `unsigned long` would be enough.

A 32 bit number can represent over 4 * 10^9. Up to 4 294 967 296.

Comment: 10^10 is more than 2^32, though.