# Will int32 be the same size on all platforms?

Tags: c++

I'm developing a multi platform app (iOS, Android, etc), using C++.

Are there base types in the C++ standard which are guaranteed to be a fixed width, and portable across multiple platforms?

I'm looking for fixed-width types such as Int32, UInt32, Int16, UInt16, Float32, etc.

Comment: C++ has neither of those.

Comment: There *is* an `int32_t`, though. For `float`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types)

Comment: @dlf There _may_ be an `int32_t`.  It's not present on all platforms.  (But the real question is: why does he want fixed width types?  There's almost no reason to use them.)

Comment: I was reading that an upcoming version of android is going to be 64bit. The new iOS devices are also 64bit (even though only a few data types have different sizes - CGFloat, pointer sizes, long). I'm writing my first major C++ project which is multi platform and I don't have much C++ experience, so my questions may not make sense. XP I was just trying to plan ahead in case there is a major change after I release my app.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Embedded systems, such as mobile phones, may need bit width specific data types.  For example, I don't believe that Android OS provides a 32-bit API to the ADC (microphone).  I haven't see any ADCs that are more than 16-bits.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Embedded systems are sometimes a bit special.  Although even then, you'd only really need the exact sized types when addressing memory mapped IO, and even then... Since you're not portable, if `short` is 16 bits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int32` is a custom typedef, only `int` exists by default. If you need a specified width take a look at [`stdint.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

```
#include <cstdint>

int32_t integer32bits;
```

I don't think any floating point counterpart exists in the standard, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Don't forget `int32_t` is optional, so to answer the question, probably not the same on all platforms. Same size for all that include it maybe.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types) addresses the issue for floats.

Comment: @chris Yeah, though a compiler error is far better than a different size, so "not the same on all platforms" is misleading.

Comment: Seems to only exist in C++11; if OP needs to support specific embedded platforms, those typedefs may not exist yet.

Comment: @BTownTKD It's not describes in C++98 AFAIK but it has existed for a while in C and many major compilers support it as an extension with semantics identical to the C++11 version. But yes, some embedded toolchains don't support it. Nothing new though, it's always been (and will remain for a long time) optional so even a full C++11 toolchain might omit it.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions in `<stdint.h>`, or `<cstdint>` can be used for portability:

- `int32_t` is guaranteed to be a typedef for a signed 32 bit type, or not exist at all. Since this is C++, you can use `enable_if` to decide on a course of action.
- `int_least32_t` is a typedef for the smallest type that has at least 32 bits
- `int_fast32_t` is a typedef for a type that has at least 32 bit and can be operated on efficiently (e.g. if the memory bus is 64 bit wide and allows no partial stores, it is faster to use a 64 bit type and waste memory rather than perform read-modify-write accesses)

See also [The difference of int8_t, int_least8_t and int_fast8_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5254051/613064).

Note that different systems can also have different endianness, so it is never safe to transmit these over the network.

Comment: Or even save them to disk.  I've seen the byte order of `long` change when I upgraded a compiler.  And of course, disks are often mounted remotely, and some of the other machines on the network will invariably have a different representation of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Floats are almost always 32 bit except on some obscure platforms that do not comply with IEEE 754. You don't need to bother with those, in all likelihood. Integer types may vary, but if your target platform has a C++11-compliant compiler, then you can use the `cstdint` header to access types of a specific size in a standard way.  If you can't use C++11,  then you will need separate code for each platform, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no such type `int32`, so I will assume you are referring to `int32_t`. And to clear up some terminology, *width* usually refers to the number of bits wide a type is, and *size* refers to the number of bytes or chars a type is wide.

Yes, an `int32_t` is required to be the same *width*, i.e., number of bits wide, on all platform that supports it, by definition. Exactly 32 bits wide. Do keep in mind that the type is optional and might not be defined at all, if and only if, the system does not have such a type, for example, if 32 is not a multiple of `CHAR_BIT`.

But their *size* in bytes (as returned by the `sizeof()` operator) depends on the value of `CHAR_BIT`. That is, the number of bits in a byte. On most systems, a byte is 8 bits, so `sizeof(int32_t)` will yield 4. But on an exotic system with 16-bit bytes, `sizeof(int32_t)` will be only 2.