The underline type for uint_fast8_t may be wider than a single byte, so the uint_fast8_t b = 0xF0; b<<4; isn't determined across different compilers?
uint_fast8_t is intended to provide the fastest possible 8-bit (or wider) integer type on the target platform, while uint8_t is a fixed 8-bit unsigned integer type.
So the uint_fast8_t b = 0xF0;  b<<4; isn't determined across different compilers?
What about when C++11 is enabled?

as Holy commented, its merely an alias. So you are basically asking whether you will see a difference between eg using some_t = uint8_t; and using some_t = uint16_t;. Perhaps that already answers the question. And this is related https://stackoverflow.com/a/35055175/4117728

If you need an 8-bit type, just use uint8_t. If there is a uint_fast8_t that is faster but still 8 bits, why isn't uint8_t using that?! Yuu don't want to code for crazy systems!


So the uint_fast8_t b = 0xF0;  b<<4; isn't determined across different compilers?

Correct.
I don't think the standard version has any effect on this.

These types are generally a bit problematic, if you want to strictly go by the book.
By definition, a compiler doesn't need to use 8-bit bytes. We have no "relevant" platforms that aren't octet-based anymore, but that's of no (real) concern to the C++ standard committee.
Thus, even std::uint8_t does not necessarily give you an 8-bit type. Although, truth be told, it's always an 8-bit type -- because if the compiler has no such type, it wouldn't even be made available. Thus, a program using uint8_t might not compile on platforms that don't use octet-sized bytes. Or it might compile with performance penalties because the compiler would add code to artificially make a type that looks octet sized while it's actually a bit larger under the hood. So yeah, that's the reason why fast and least variations exist.
Which means, in theory, you might want to use std::uint_least8_t instead -- which brings you to the same problem you mentioned, but at least it's going to be more likely to actually compile on such weird platforms.
Also, you could "force" octet-sized values by adding &0xff, and hope that a) compilers on normal platforms will completely ignore that, and b) they won't warn about it either. Or else you'd have to stick it into an inline function and disable that warning in there.
At this stage, I don't know whether compilers on any "normal" platform even make uint_fast8_t different from uint8_t. Or whether anyone actually uses uint_fast8_t for anything...
At the end of the day, I use uintX_t, and don't really care about the other variations, until I actually run into a situation where it matters. This includes loops too -- it's certainly conceivable to make a loop counter use uint_least32_t/uint_fast32_t if the end-value is a uint32_t, but it's too much work for my taste.

Looked at all the toolchains I have around, all have fast8 as 8 bits. But if you want an example of different sizes, fast16 is larger than 16 bits almost everywhere.
