# Printing guarantee of uintX_t and intX_t types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I want to know whether there is a standard if I use `uint16_t` type for a variable and want to print it out on screen by using `std::cout <<`, it is printed as number not `char`. I read on some tutorial websites that `uint8_t` or `int8_t` prints doesn't guarantee as character or number. Yet, I can't find any clause or quotation from standard. Do I need always casting to be sure to get the wished output for all these mentioned types?

Comment: I don't believe there's a guarantee. `int8_t` is very likely to be a typedef for `char` or `signed char` on most implementations. `uint16_t` is likely an `unsigned short` on most implementations - but the standard doesn't prohibit an implementation where `char` is 16 bits large.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: "*the standard doesn't prohibit an implementation where char is 16 bits large.*" Actually, it does. The `int*_t` types are required to be *exactly* that size. And `char` is required to be the *smallest* possible type; a "byte" in C++ is defined as the `sizeof(char)`, which shall be 1. Therefore, it's impossible to implement `int16_t` as a `char`, since that would leave no smaller type for `int8_t`.

Comment: @NicolBolas The implementation is not required to provide a type for every width. "**[cstdint.syn]/2** The header defines all types and macros the same as the C standard library header `<stdint.h>`." The C standard: "**7.20/4** ... Conversely, for each type described herein that the implementation does not provide, `<stdint.h>` shall not declare that typedef name..."

Comment: @NicolBolas only `int_leastN_t` and `int_fastN_t` are required. [Fixed-width types will not be available if the implementation can't provide them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5254157/995714). If CHAR_BIT > 8 on some platform then obviously int8_t won't exist there

Comment: @phuclv: I know they're not required, but if you're going to ask whether `uint16_t` is a typedef for an `unsigned char`, then *by definition* you're assuming that `uint16_t` is a thing your implementation provides. Otherwise the question is meaningless.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm taking about what you said *Therefore, it's impossible to implement `int16_t` as a `char`, since that would leave no smaller type for `int8_t`* which is wrong. If `CHAR_BIT == 16` (which is allowed by the standard) then `int8_t` doesn't exist and `uint16_t` can be typedef'ed as `char`, in which case `std::cout << uint16_t(x)` can print out a character

Comment: @phuclv: "*I'm taking about what you said*" Yes, but Igor already quoted the standard showing that I was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If `uint8_t` is defined by the implementation, then `uint16_t` cannot be a `char`. The reason being that `char` is defined to be the smallest addressable value; `sizeof(char)` is explicitly 1.

Since these optional sized types are required to be *exactly* of the specified size, `sizeof(uint16_t)` is required to be greater than `sizeof(uint8_t)`. And since `sizeof(uint8_t)` cannot be smaller than `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(uint16_t)` can't be 1. So it can't be a `char`.

Of course, if `uint8_t` is *not defined* but `uint16_t` is defined, then all bets are off. But if your code already assumes that both `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` exist, then you can likewise assume that `uint16_t` isn't a `char`.